# Core Data: ManagedObjectContext is Null

Tags: swift, core-data

In Swift, I am trying to save to Core data and am receiving this error:

"+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSPersistentStoreCoordinator for searching for entity name"

Looking through previous SO answers, it seems that the managedObjectContext is null.

I don't see why it is null. I set it inside the IBAction before I pass it in.

View Controller

```
var appDelegate: AppDelegate!
var managedContext: NSManagedObjectContext!

*IBAction* {
        appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        managedContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .MainQueueConcurrencyType)

        let est = EstablishmentCoreData(context: managedContext)          
}
```

EstablishmentCoreData.swift

```
class EstablishmentCoreData: NSManagedObject {
    // Insert code here to add functionality to your managed object subclass
    init (context: NSManagedObjectContext) {        
        if let ent = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("EstablishmentCoreData", inManagedObjectContext: context) {
            super.init(entity: ent, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
            self.title = "Title"          
        }
        else {
            fatalError("ERROR")
        }
    }
}
```

EstablishmentCoreData+CoreDataProperties.swift

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

extension EstablishmentCoreData {
    @NSManaged var title: String?
}
```

Comment: Where do you create this managed object context, does it (or one of it's parents) have a non-nil persistent store coordinator?

Comment: @Jonah I created it in the ViewController.swift file. The AppDelgate file has the persistent store controller

Comment: Your error states that the persistent store coordinator is nil. If you think that's not the case then please show where you create this context and set its coordinator.